# Will I have problems if I purchase a one-way ticket

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, one-way

I will be flying with Qatar from the UK to Doha (a connecting flight) then to Doha to India. I also have an oci card (indian life long visa) which allows me to come and go as I please.

So would doha or indian immigration say anything or would there be any problems?

Edit: 
I looked on qatar airways website and it said that a visa is not needed for transit in doha if the individual has a onward ticket. I'm sorry if i sound stupid but would this be the ticket from doha to india or are the asking for a return ticket?

Also can qatar stop anyone from boarding if they do not have a return ticket?

Hope this makes a little more sense

Edit:
Right .... ok I just wanted to make sure and now some people have confused me even more into thinking I won't be able to board the plane?...

Comment: Which Immigration are youo wondering about - the Qatar immigration in Doha (assuming you go landside), or the Indian immigration?

Comment: @gagravarr well doha is just a connecting flight so I don't think they would say anything as my final destination is india. But if you could tell me both that would help.

Comment: An 'onward ticket' just means a ticket out of Doha. So you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: I looked on qatar airways website and it said that a visa is not needed for transit in doha if the individual has a onward ticket. I'm sorry if i sound stupid but would this be the ticket from doha to india or are the asking for a return ticket?

Onwards mean onwards. Every country minds its own borders and so this here means as long as you leave Qatar pretty much ASAP you don't need a visa.

Still, they will check whether your visa situation is OK with the target country (because if not then they will need to carry you back and they will be fined). However, you can enter India without a problem.

In general, the airline really can only check whether you have a visa (or visa exempt) there is no guarantee for you or for them you will be admitted in fact. The system is intended to filter out most who will be turned around, it's totally flawed, stupid and should be redone (preclearance via video conference for example) but I am wondering off topic.

Comment: So are you saying without a return ticket I won't be able to board? Even if I have a long life visa to my designated country? Oci card

Comment: You can certainly board. What I am saying is the exact opposite: even if you had a good chance of being denied at the border you'd be allowed to board on the power of your visa! Airlines are not border guards.

Comment: Oh ok.... I'm just getting so confused because everyone is saying different things. I just want to be safe than sorry.  I want to go to.india and I have a life long visa so I can stay there as long as I want so a return ticket wouldn't actually make sense in my situation. But a lot of people have been saying that airlines (I'll be travelling with qatar airlines) sometimes don't allow people to board without a return ticket. It just wouldn't make sense for me because I have family there also my visa allows me to stay as long as I want so a return ticket as a requirement wouldn't make sense

Comment: @IramAhmed airlines will deny boarding for those without a return ticket if they think that the lack of a return ticket will cause the traveler to be refused entry on arrival.  Your OCI card makes this unlikely.

Comment: Yes.... but when boarding the airline doesn't ask to show visa only your boarding pass and passport

Comment: I also contacted indian immigration and the also said that an oci card holder does not require a return ticket so if but very unlikely to happen, the airline did ask I could also show them the email as well as my visa of required

Comment: @IramAhmed A lot of people don't know what they're talking about. When the airline checks your documents, they will use [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=GB&EM=GB&DE=IN&TR=QA&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) as a reference, and it will plainly tell them that anyone with an Overseas Citizen of India card or booklet does not need a visa (or return tickets). When you check in with the airline, present your passport and OCI card.

Comment: @michael Hampton hi yes it says that return tickets are needed for those who have tourist or buisness visas. However return tickets are not needed for a pio card holder, I did have a pio card but I got it converted to an oci. However it doesn't say that those with an oci card do or do not need a return ticket

Comment: @IramAhmed Timatic only mentions the return ticket requirement if it actually exists.

Comment: @michael Hampton it says that a pio card holder does not need a return ticket. But how would one no if you do need one for an oci if it isn't stated...I'm sorry I'm just very confused and want to be safe than sorry

Comment: @IramAhmed Again, if it's not stated there, then it's not required.

Comment: @michael Hampton ok I don't understand why it has such specific detail for pio card but not for oci